# facebook image save curl

Tags: php, facebook, curl, get

The size of the save images  0 kb

Working code, except facebook

```
 function imagedownload($url,$saveto){
                $ch = curl_init ($url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
                $result = parse_url($url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $result['scheme'].'://'.$result['host']);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0');
                $raw=curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close ($ch);
                if(file_exists($saveto)){
                unlink($saveto);
                }
                $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
                fwrite($fp, $raw);
                fclose($fp);
                }

                $url="http://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/cp0/e15/q65/p320x320/13700038_850487491753797_6227258625184891703_n.jpg?oh=793ecde8db1a8e65789534907d08b25e&oe=57F1DDFF";

                $konum="images/"

                $yolla=imagedownload($url,$konum);
```

The size of the save images  0 kb

Working code, except facebook

Answer (score 0):

It works if you remove the options to `POST` and do a regular `GET` request:

```
<?php

function imagedownload($url, $saveto)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $result = parse_url($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $result['scheme'] . '://' . $result['host']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0');
    $raw = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if (file_exists($saveto)) {
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto, 'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}

$url = "http://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/cp0/e15/q65/p320x320/13700038_850487491753797_6227258625184891703_n.jpg?oh=793ecde8db1a8e65789534907d08b25e&oe=57F1DDFF";
$konum = "test.jpg";

$yolla = imagedownload($url, $konum);
```

Comment: but the problem continues

Comment: It works for me so try enabling `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`, and seeing what it says.

Answer (score 0):

I had try in my localhost this code and it working well.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
function imagedownload($url,$saveto){
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
    unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}
$url="http://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/cp0/e15/q65/p320x320/13700038_850487491753797_6227258625184891703_n.jpg?oh=793ecde8db1a8e65789534907d08b25e&oe=57F1DDFF";
$konum="/var/www/html/jsPDF-master/examples/test.jpg";
$yolla=imagedownload($url,$konum);
?>
```

And result

[image]

And one note: Please make sure the directory for save image must have write permission.

Example: chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/jsPDF-master/examples

Or ensure that in php.ini allow_url_fopen is enable